# CSS change button style after click

Tags: css, button, styling

I was wondering if there was a way to change a button's style, in css, after it's been clicked, so not a `element:active`.

Comment: can you paste code here and little more explanation ?

Comment: You could add a jQuery function to add an extra class to the button on click

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure css option, try using the :focus pseudo class.

```
#style  {
    background-color: red;
}

#style:focus {     
    background-color:yellow;    
}
```

Answer (score 71):

Each link has five different states: `link`, `hover`, `active`, `focus` and `visited`.

`Link` is the normal appearance, `hover` is when you mouse over, `active` is the state when it's clicked, `focus` follows active and `visited` is the state you end up when you unfocus the recently clicked link.

I'm guessing you want to achieve a different style on either `focus` or `visited`, then you can add the following CSS:

```
a { color: #00c; }
a:visited { #ccc; }
a:focus { #cc0; }
```

A recommended order in your CSS to not cause any trouble is the following:

```
a
a:visited { ... }
a:focus { ... }
a:hover { ... }
a:active { ... }
```

You can use your web browser's developer tools to force the states of the element like this (Chrome->Developer Tools/Inspect Element->Style->Filter :hov):
[Force state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQlOd.png)

Comment: In most cases using the anchor tags :visited state will be the cleanest css only implementation of a button with a clicked state.  You could also repurpose a checkbox :checked http://jsfiddle.net/4hrzf39g/2/ but its a bit much imo.

Comment: "focus follows active" is not ... very clear

Answer (score 16):

It is possible to do with CSS only by selecting active and focus pseudo element of the button.

```
button:active{
    background:olive;
}

button:focus{
    background:olive;
}
```

See codepen: http://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/Bpqdqx

You could also write a simple jQuery click function which changes the background color.

HTML:

```
<button class="js-click">Click me!</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  background: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
  $( ".js-click" ).click(function() {
    $( ".js-click" ).css('background', 'green');
  });
```

Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/pRxrVG

Answer (score 14):

Try to check outline on button's focus:

```
button:focus {
    outline: blue auto 5px; 
}
```

If you have it, just set it to `none`.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. The border property was not enough, it was outline that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

What is the code of your button? If it's an a tag, then you could do this:

```css
a {
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
}
a:visited {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">A button</a>
```

Or you could use jQuery to add a class on click, as below:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#button").addClass('button-clicked');
});
```

```css
.button-clicked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

If your button would be an `<a>` element, you could use the `:visited` selector.

You are limited however, you can only change:

- color
- background-color
- border-color (and its sub-properties)
- outline-color
- The color parts of the fill and stroke properties

I haven't read [this article about revisiting the `:visited`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/) but maybe some smarter people have found more ways to hack it.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way of doing this is to use JavaScript like so:

```
element.addEventListener('click', (e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    element.style = '<insert CSS here as you would in a style attribute>';
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

all answers is true for hover, focus,...
if you want change background-color when you click and be stay that clicked state, you could do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script>
    const element = document.querySelector("body")
    let taskDone = false
   
    // function for show button
    const elementShow = () => {
      element.innerHTML = `
        <button id="done-button" style="background-color : ${!taskDone 
          ? "#4dd432" : "#fd67ad"};" onclick=doneTask()>
          ${!taskDone ? "Done" : "not done yet"}
        </button>
        `
    }
    elementShow()

    // click Done button
    const doneTask = () => {
      taskDone = (taskDone ? false : true)
      elementShow()
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with :focus.

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```